# All combinations - LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have 3 tables(Objects in my OR mapping model, whatever). Let's call them TABLE1, TABLE2, and TABLE3 => actual names are in Czech, i think this will be better as example.

1)TABLE1 has 1-N relationship with TABLE2.
2)TABLE1 has also 1-N relationship with TABLE3. So the tables look something like this:

```
    TABLE2
    {
       int ID;
       nvarchar attributeT2;
       int TABLE1_FK;
    }

    TABLE1
    {
       int ID;
    }

    TABLE3
    {
       int ID;
       nvarchar attributeT3
       int TABLE1_FK;
    }
```

Now i need all combinations of: TABLE2 records where attributeT2 == "T2" and TABLE3 records where attributeT3 == "T3" BUT those two must have the same TABLE1_FK(= they must be joined by TABLE1 record).

So if there were 2 records in TABLE2 with TABLE1_FK ==1, and 2 records in TABLE3 with TABLE1_FK == 1, i need all combinations == 4 pairs. I could do this by foreach cycle, and querying the DB in each step, but i think that would be very ineffective, and i was wondering if there was a better way.

I thought it could be something like this:

```
    var query= from x in context.TABLE2
               where x.attributeT2 == "T2"
               join y in context.TABLE3 on x.TABLE1_FK == y.TABLE1_FK
               where y.attributeT3 == "T3"
               select new WrapperClass(x,y);
```

But the combinations are wrong - the pair does not always have the same TABLE1_FK. Thanks a milion for any response.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check it myself, but maybe worths to try. The idea is to join on FK columns in TABLE2 and TABLE3 and have where condition for attibuteT3 and attributeT2

```
var query= from x in context.TABLE2
           join y in context.TABLE3 on x.TABLE1_FK == y.TABLE1_FK
           where y.attributeT3 == "T3" && x.attributeT2 == "T2"
           select new WrapperClass(x,y);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am SO sorry, but 2 minutes after i'd hit the submit button, i thought of something i haven't tried.

```
        var asdf = from x in context.TABLE1
                   join y in context.TABLE2 on x.ID equals y.TABLE1_FK
                   where y.attributeT2 == "T2"
                   join z in context.TABLE3S on x.ID equals z.TABLE1_FK
                   where z.attributeT3 == "T3"
                   select new WrapperClass(y,z);
```

It worked. Thanks a lot anyway Michael.